# installing Tezos client on Intel Mac OS

Tags: tezos-client

I'm a complete beginner who needs help installing the tezos client correctly.

I installed tezos-client and configured tezos client endpoint to a private node following these docs: https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/#mac-os

However, when I try to import my secret key through './tezos-client import secret key (secret key) unencrypted: '

I get 'No such file or directory when there is a tezos-client file in the folder which I checked through 'ls'

So I tried to delete the Tezos client and reinstall it in the 'tezos' folder I created under Documents but I get the same problem and now I can't even see the 'tezos-client' in the folder I created..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `brew` for the installation it shouldn't be necessary to call `tezos-client` from a specific directory.

In other words you should be able to run:

```
tezos-client import secret key <secret_key> <uri>
```

without prefixing it with `./`.

BTW if you only want to use stable versions, I suggest reinstalling it with:

```
brew tap serokell/tezos-packaging-stable https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging-stable.git
brew install tezos-client
```

(notice the `stable` part) as explained on the [tezos-packaging docs here](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/blob/master/docs/distros/macos.md#brew-tap-for-macos).

Comment: Okay thanks, what is the URi part if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: The URI there is used to specify the signing scheme used for the secret key.
E.g. for unencrypted keys it would look something like `unencrypted:edks...`

You can learn more by running `tezos-client list signing schemes`